# How to add custom filed value after in wp post title

Tags: custom-field, meta-value, wp-title

(WP Post Title)Malwarebytes Anti-Malware (Custom field value)3.5.1.2522

How to add custome meta value in wordpress after wp post title in same hyperlink

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple 3 step process:

1. Look for your post title markup that should look something like:

> ```
> <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
> ```

2. Now, get your post custom meta value through:

> ```
> <?php $bannerContent = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bannerContent', true); ?>
> ```

3. Next add this value to your title where ever you need:

> ```
> <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();  echo $bannerContent; ?></a></h1>
> ```

This is it. If you need any further assistance, please let us know!
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change displayed title in template file (e.g. content.php):

```
$custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_meta_key, true);
if ( is_single() ) {
    the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
} elseif ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
    the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">',
        ' ' . $custom_field . '</a></h3>' );
} else {
    the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', 
        ' ' . $custom_field . '</a></h2>' );
}
```

You can also use `the_title` filter hook (code goes to functions.php):

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'modify_post_title' );

function modify_post_title( $title ) {
    global $post;
    //
    // --- show on list and single post view
    // if ( $post->post_type == 'post' && in_the_loop() ) {
    // --- show only in single post view
    // if ( is_singular() && $post->post_type == 'post' && in_the_loop() ) {

    // when to apply custom field suffix
    // --- when type is "post" and when it's not a single post view
    if ( !is_singular() && $post->post_type == 'post' && in_the_loop() ) {
        // $custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_meta_key, true);
        $title .= $custom_field;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

It depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: please showing $custom_field in single post title (remove is_singular)

Comment: do you want to append custom field to title in single post view? or title in single post is changed also, but you don't want change title there? @WakilDJ

Comment: not showing custom field value in single post? please add this $custom_field in the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); thank you

Comment: to show `$custom_field` on list and single post view use: `if ( $post->post_type == 'post' && in_the_loop() )`, to show **only** in single post view use: `if ( is_singular() && $post->post_type == 'post' && in_the_loop() )`.  @WakilDJ

Answer (score 0):

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 2 );
function append_query_string( $url, $post ) 
{
    return $url.'?var_name='.get_post_meta($post->ID,'meta_key',true);
}